# Best way to encrypt data and prevent replay attacks over HTTP

Tags: http, security, encryption, iot, gateway

I'm working on IoT gateway which will collect data from IoT devices. IoT device is a constrained device which couldn't use HTTPS.
It sends periodically small amount of data - from sensors, with some aditional information as time, message id, unit id etc.

Right now we've got an implementation of gateway as REST API in Java open for everyone. So It accepts requests as JSON from any device, without ensuring that data comes from our device are not corupted or compromised.

Without having ability to secure data by HTTPS, what is the best way to design interface between gateway and device?

Comment: <RANT> *IoT device is a constrained device which couldn't use HTTPS*. And you can blame this not on the crypto but on the IETF for failing to deliver implementable protocols. It's a fact that TLS is now so huge and complicated that it's almost impossible to implement except by huge organizations with many programmers, or by a small number of coding savants. The situation is almost as bad as using patented algorithms.</RANT> Although I'm not very familiar with it I hear the NOISE protocol is much smaller and easier to implement.

Answer (score 2):

> Without having ability to secure data by HTTPS, what is the best way to design interface between gateway and device?

You can still use a symmetric encryption/authentication to ensure integrity and confidentiality, which should be feasible even for low end devices

As an inspiration you may have a loot at [JWE with a shared key](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jwe-with-shared-key).

You could limit replays using some timestamp/counter or having idempotent consumers.

Regardless that - missing tls/https ypu have to take care of a lot of things, such as how to protect a shared key, update if revoked, etc

Answer (score 0):

If the device can't do https (with any set of cipher suites) you will probably have to make serious compromises and not have some aspects of a secure connection. A bit simplified, but https is pretty much the minimal full suite of how it can be done, there is nothing "unnecessary". You might not need everything, but it entirely depends on your usecase and threat model. Before implementing this, you should have a full understanding of exactly what https provides, and how, so you can use applicable parts. Also note that this is not at all straightforward to implement, a custom implementation will likely be vulnerable.

Comment: *A bit simplified, but https is pretty much the minimal full suite of how it can be done, there is nothing "unnecessary"...* Just to register a dissenting view, it is my opinion that just the opposite is true: both HTTP and TLS are full of trash from stem to stern.

Comment: I meant more like what it provides. Server (or even mutual) authentication, key exchange, encryption, protection against replay or reordering and so on. If the asker wants a secure protocol (over http as I understood), he would probably need most of these. And that's what https _is for_, and well known, reasonably secure with tls 1.2+. I'm not at all saying it can't be done any other way, of course it can. But it needs a _lot_ of expertese in areas the asker likely doesn't have. I don't think we disagree so much, but I'm careful in my advice to really try to help in the end.

Comment: Take a look at UDP over DTLS for a relatively simpler, leaner, cleaner approach to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

How constrained is your device really? There are small implementations of TLS that wouldn't require you to compromise on security such as [wolfSSL](https://www.wolfssl.com/).

> Footprint sizes (compiled binary size) for wolfSSL range between 20-100kB depending on build options and the compiler being used.
>   Regarding runtime memory usage, wolfSSL will generally consume between 1-36 kB per SSL/TLS session.

Anyway, I would not recommend you try and implement your own cipher suite unless you REALLY know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Given the kind of tools you've mentioned having access to (HTTP/JSON), I suggest looking at JOSE, which is a standardized way of signing and encrypting this kind of data. Specifically you'll be interested in [JWE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516), [JWS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515), and [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519). The learning curve for JOSE is unfortunately somewhat steep and the docs are somewhat sparse, but it is quite effective and implemented on a variety of platforms, and will save you a lot of headache in inventing your own protocols (which is quite difficult to do correctly). I've had pretty good luck building custom systems around JOSE.

There are some key questions you need to ask:

- Do you need mutual authentication, or only authentication of the device? If the device only writes and never reads, then you likely only need to authenticate the device and not the server.
- Can you accept the risk of a single shared secret baked into the devices? The problem with a single shared secret is that if any device is reverse engineered, then all protection is lost until you phase out all devices with that key.
- Can you accept the manufacturing cost of a per-device secret? Depending on your manufacturing process, generating a unique secret for each device may be difficult.
- Can you accept the on-device storage space and processing requirements of a client certificate? If not, can you accept the logistics of maintaining a server-side database of every device's key? (If you can except neither, then you'll have to go with a single shared secret for the whole system.)

My gut feeling is you're talking about a device that can handle the complexity of a client cert, but not a full HTTPS stack. If you also can handle the complexity of generating a certificate during manufacturing, or your customers are willing to register their devices, then I recommend the following:

- During manufacture or registration, generate a certificate and signing request. Send it to your server to be signed, and install the signed X.509 on the device. (Generating a CSR on the device is also an option, but many small devices lack the entropy to generate a decent random number. There are tradeoffs either way.)
- Generate a certificate for the server, and install its public key on all devices.
- Assuming the amount of data you're sending is small, I'd bundle it all into the JWT (web token), encrypted to the server's public key, and signed with the client's private key. Typically JWTs are used to exchange authentication information, but they're really just a standardized container for sending signed and encrypted JSON data, so they really can be anything you want.
- In order to prevent replay attacks, the server needs to keep track of messages its seen before. There are two main approaches I like, depending on your situation:

  - Make the jti (JWT ID) a combination of the timestamp and a random value (in which case the server just needs to keep a cache of recent JTIs and reject too-old timestamps)
  - Make the jti a combination of the device id and a monotonically increasing message id. The server then needs to keep track of the last-seen message id for each device, and reject any ids less-than-or-equal to that.

If you don't need encryption, look at JWS instead, which just signs the data. None of these techniques require encryption, and it's a little simpler if you take that part out (you don't need a server certificate, for example). You can still prevent replays, and only allow trusted clients to connect. It is possible for someone to reverse engineer your device and pull out its client cert. The advantage of a client cert is that if you discover the abuse, you can then just ban that one cert. With a shared secret you can't do that.

The basic advantage of all of this is that JOSE is based on JSON, which is something you already understand and know how to parse and work with. But it's also reasonably compact for a string-based protocol. It's also extremely flexible in terms of algorithms, which makes it much easier to implement on smaller hardware. You could build all the same things by hand using public/private keys, but JOSE has already thought through many of the tricky security problems.

If only it were better documented....